# Hard to understand material without diagrams on moving commits from one branch to another

Tags: git, rebase

I don't understand the content from page https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#move_commit:

> ### Moving a commit from one branch to another
>
> So, you have a commit which is in the wrong place and you want to move
>   it from one branch to another. In order to do this, you will need to
>   know the SHA of the first and last commit (in a continuous series of
>   commits) you want to move (those values are the same if you are moving
>   only one commit), the name of the branch you are moving the commit
>   from, and the name of the branch you are moving the commit to. In the
>   example below, I will name these four values $first, $last, $source,
>   and $destination (respectively). Additionally, you will need to use a
>   [nonce](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonce) branch as a placeholder.
>   I will call the nonce branch "nonce" in the following example.
>   However, you may use any branch name that is not currently in use. You
>   can delete it immediately after you are done.
>
> ```
> git branch nonce $last
> git rebase -p --onto $destination $first^ nonce
> ```
>
> Remember that when you substitute $first in the command above, leave
>   the "^" alone, it is literal.
>
> Use `gitk --all --date-order` to check to make sure the move looks
>   correct (pretending that nonce is the destination branch). Please
>   check very carefully if you were trying to move a merge, it may have
>   been recreated improperly. If you don't like the result, you may
>   delete the nonce branch (`git branch -D nonce`) and try again.
>
> However, if everything looks good, we can move the actual destination
>   branch pointer to where nonce is:
>
> ```
> git checkout $destination
> git reset --hard nonce
> git branch -d nonce
> ```
>
> If you double-checked with `gitk --all --date-order`, you would see
>   that the destination branch looks correct. However, the commits are
>   still on the source branch as well. We can get rid of those now:
>
> ```
> git rebase -p --onto $first^ $last $source
> ```
>
> Using `gitk --all --date-order` one last time, you should now see that
>   the commits on the source branch have gone away. You have successfully
>   moved the commits. Please check very carefully if merges occurred
>   after the commits which were deleted. They may have been recreated
>   incorrectly. If so you can either [undo the
>   delete](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitFixUm/fixup.html#undo_tip)
>   or try to delete the bad merge and try to recreate it manually, or
>   create a fake (--ours) merge from the same SHA so that git is aware
>   that the merge occurred.

I'll try to explain what I do know and what I don't get. I would appreciate it if someone draws a tree of commits after each command.

First,

```
git branch nonce $last   (1)
git rebase -p --onto $destination $first^ nonce   (2)
```

As I understand it (1) copies commit $last to branch named nonce. In (2), range of commits from $first to nonce inclusive is moved on top of $destination. I don't understand how tree of commits would look at this point, because i don't quite get the effect of (1).

Then,

```
git checkout $destination   (3)
git reset --hard nonce   (4)
git branch -d nonce   (5)
```

(3) checks out destination commit. Then at (4) hard resets to nonce but what is the effect of that? Then at (5) delete branch nonce.

Lastly,

```
git rebase -p --onto $first^ $last $source   (6)
```

The text says (6) results in commits in source branch being deleted. As I understand this syntax, this puts range of commits defined as children of $last up to and including $source on top of parent of $first.

I do know the syntax of `git rebase --onto`. But I don't get what exactly is going on here.

I would appreciate it if you help me by drawing a diagram of tree of commits after each command.

Comment: I suggest this interactive service to learn git [learngitbranching](https://learngitbranching.js.org/?locale=ru_RU)

Answer (score 2):

Part of the confusion here probably comes from the terminology "moving commits". Technically there is no such thing as moving a commit. Once a commit is created its content as well as parent pointer is immutable and can never ever be changed.

It is however possible to create new commits *with a different parent* that achieves the same change, which is what is happening in this particular case.

It is also useful to remember that branches are just mutable pointers to commits.

**Starting point:**
Let's assume the followig

- `$destination` is the target branch
- `$source` is the source branch
- `$first` is `C` (The first commit in the series we want to "move")
- `$last` is `D` (The last commit in the series we want to "move")

```
                      $destination
                           |  
A -- B ------------------- F
      \ -- C -- D ----- E
                        |
                     $source
```

**Step 1: `git branch nonce $last`**

- Attaches a new branch pointer called `nonce` to the `$last` commit

```
                      $destination
                           |  
A -- B ------------------- F
      \ -- C -- D ----- E
                |       |
              $nonce  $source
```

**Step 2: `git rebase -p --onto $destination $first^ nonce`**

- Takes all the diffs between the parent of `$first` and `nonce` (i.e the changes introduced by `C` and `D`) and applies them as new commits on top of `$destination`
- This results in new commits `C'` and `D'` (Original commits `C` and `D` are not affected)

  - The `nonce` branch pointer is moved to the last of the newly created commits `D'`

```
                      $destination
                           |  
A -- B ------------------- F 
      \ -- C -- D ----- E   \ -- C' -- D'        
                        |              | 
                     $source        $nonce
```

**Step 3: `git checkout $destination`**

- Changes the working copy to the `$destination` branch. This has no impact on the history graph

**Step 4: `git reset --hard nonce`**

- Moves the `$destination` branch pointer to the same commit as `nonce`
- Could also (and probably more commonly) done by `git merge --ff-only nonce`, which should result in a fast forward merge and thus yield the same result.

```
                                 $destination
                                      |  
A -- B ------------------- F -- C' -- D'
      \ -- C -- D ----- E             |         
                        |           $nonce                
                     $source
```

**Step 5: `git branch -d nonce`**

- Deletes the `nonce` branch pointer

```
                                 $destination
                                      |  
A -- B ------------------- F -- C' -- D'
      \ -- C -- D ----- E                     
                        |                           
                     $source
```

**Step 6: `git rebase -p --onto $first^ $last $source`**

- Takes all the diffs between `$last` and `$source` (i.e the changes introduced by `E`) and applies them as new commits on top of `$first^` (the parent of `$first`, i.e `B`)
- This results in new commits `E'` (Original commits `E` is not affected)

```
                                 $destination
                                      |  
A -- B ------------------- F -- C' -- D'
      \ -- C -- D ----- E
       \-- E'                     
           |                           
        $source
```

From an outside view, the effect of commits `C` and `D` have been removed from `$source` and applied to `$destination` instead.

**EDIT:**
As can be seen above, the original commits `C` and `D` are still present, but are not reachable from any branch, they are "detached". They still exist in the repository however since git is very strict about not removing or modifying existing commits (they are immutable after all). To explicitly remove this commits, use `git prune`

```
                                 $destination
                                      |  
A -- B ------------------- F -- C' -- D'
      \-- E'                     
          |                           
       $source
```